# Googleupdate "user account control"

Tags: uac, google-updates

Out of the blue, now I'm getting the UAC dialog prompt for googleupdate.exe.  I've had this program on my system for more than a year now, with not a problem.  Perhaps there was a silent update or something.

In any case, since googleupdate runs about once an hour, this is quite annoying.  Why did this happen?  What is best way to stop the UAC prompt while letting googleupdate do it's thing?

I know there are a lot of questions related to UAC, but I'd like to know specific ways to deal with this, in regards to, googleupdate.

Comment: You can always go into the task scheduler and change how often it is updating (I know not an answer but may be OK for a work around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave's comment on the task scheduler got me thinking a bit.  A looked into there and I had multiple (not just 2 which would seem to be the norm) and I remember disabling this a few times with MSConfig utility.  When you disable googleupdate this way, it eventually just adds a new entry. (another story)

In any case, several of the googleupdate tasks in the task scheduler had my user account as the account to run this under, while the old ones just had SYSTEM.  So, I removed the ones that had my account (which is an admin account, so shouldn't make a difference right?) and everything seems to working smoothly now.